# How do I re-fire or get useEffect to update after url parameter change to show a different API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-hooks, use-effect

Hello I'll preface this by saying that I am pretty new to React and coding in general. I am currently going through the React Doc and learning. So sorry if this is trivial.

I am having an issue code here : https://pastebin.com/rkwS1x66 where I am trying to update a table based on a user clicking a button. I'm confident that my logic is solid up until the actual render. My click handling function works fine and on toggle it can display the url change through an alert(). The problem is that although the URL variable changes, the table does not re-render. I want the table to essentially re-render and show the different API call. Basically, it should show either the SWAP api or Pokemon api rendered in the table dynamically based on the button click.

The link contains my condensed code. My project contains more code but I thought this would suffice for the issue at hand.

```js
function HeaderSection() {
 
  let baseUrl = "https://swapi.dev/api/people";
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [currentStatus , setStatus] = useState(false);
 
  let urlToggle = false;
 
  function urlChange(){
    urlToggle = !urlToggle;
    if(urlToggle)
    {
      baseUrl = "https://swapi.dev/api/people";
    }
    else
    {
      baseUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry";
    }
  }
 
  
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(baseUrl)
    .then((response) =>{
      if(!response.ok)
      {
        return Promise.reject( new Error("Response Error!"));
      }
      else
      {
        return response.json();
      }
    })
    .catch ( (err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
    .then((json) => {
      try{
        setData(json.results);
        setStatus(true);
      }
      catch
      {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(`State Error!: Data: ${data} , Connection:${currentStatus}`));
      }
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    })  
  },[baseUrl]);
 
  return (
    <div className='gio-main'>
     
      <div className='gio-container-3'>
       <h1>API Switch</h1>
       <h4>Endpoint request using vanilla JS displayed in custom table</h4>
       <p>You can switch between endpoints using this button!</p>
       <button onClick={urlChange}>Change API</button>
       {!currentStatus ?  <h2>Loading... </h2> : <Table data={data}/>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default HeaderSection;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your `useEffect` hook isn't triggering on `baseUrl`
and changes the value of `data` as you expect is that `baseUrl` isn't a state.

The second argument, the list of the `useEffect` expect states, and will cause the `useEffect` to ttriger on state change, so using a "normal" variable will not cause the hook to trigger.

To fix it simply change `baseUrl` to a `useState`.
In your code:

```
// change #1
const [baseUrl, setBaseUrl] = useState("https://swapi.dev/api/people");

//change #2
  function urlChange(){
    urlToggle = !urlToggle;
    if(urlToggle)
    {
      setBaseUrl("https://swapi.dev/api/people");
    }
    else
    {
      setBaseUrl("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry");
    }
  }
```

And now when the baseUrl changes the `useEffect` hook will retrigger.

[useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) - look at the "note" part

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you and now I realize more so to remember I need to manage my state with useState!